# Do nested Suspense components cause a sequential or a parallel load?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, code-splitting, react-suspense

I understand that Suspense components are the React-ian approach to [code splitting](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html), which makes webpages load faster. Now, say you have a component hierarchy like this:

```js
<App>
  <Suspense fallback={<FirstLoader/>}>
    <OuterWrapper>
      <Suspense fallback={<SecondLoader/>}>
        <InnerWrapper>
          {content}
        </InnerWrapper>
      </Suspense>
    </OuterWrapper>
  </Suspense>
</App>
```

Assume first that only `InnerWrapper` is lazy-loaded, and in the second case they are both lazy loaded.

Does React defer the loading of `InnerWrapper` after `OuterWrapper` is loaded, or are they both loaded simultaneously? Specifically, whether the rendering of the 2nd Suspense's fallback is deferred after the first component is loaded.

Comment: Are `OuterWrapper` and `InnerWrapper` lazy loaded?

Comment: Just edited the question body

Comment: by loaded you mean committed to the DOM?

Comment: Yes. Specifically, whether the rendering of the 2nd Suspense's fallback is deferred after the first component is loaded. I couldn't figure this out in my app because they're loading too fast.

Comment: The second Suspense only renders when `OuterWrapper` is loaded and rendered. I might provide an example to prove that if I find some time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does React defer the loading of InnerWrapper after OuterWrapper is loaded, or are they both loaded simultaneously? Specifically, whether the rendering of the 2nd Suspense's fallback is deferred after the first component is loaded.

Rendering of the second `Suspense` will be delayed until `OuterWrapper`. Everything you pass to `OuterWrapper` as children:

```
     <Suspense fallback={<SecondLoader/>}>
        <InnerWrapper>
          {content}
        </InnerWrapper>
      </Suspense>
```

Is passed to `OuterWrapper` as `props.children` when it is going to be rendered. So, rendering of second `Suspense` can only happen when `OuterWrapper` is fetched and executed.

Also, in the case when `InnerWrapper` is lazy-loaded, it going to be fetched after `OuterWrapper` is rendered. So, in this case, both components aren't fetched in parallel but one after another.

I've created an example to show it here: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/dusty-ghoul

you can play with delay after which scripts are going to be send to the client by modifying `delay` parameter here:

```
// public/index.js
const OuterWrapper = React.lazy(() => import("./OuterWrapper.js?delay=5000"));
const InnerWrapper = React.lazy(() => import("./InnerWrapper.js?delay=1000"));
```